# Significato di "buse"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese, ho letto:

> Ma questo era niente rispetto alla vita che faceva adesso quel Cinto. Suo padre gli era sempre addosso, lo sorvegliava dalla vigna, le due donne lo chiamavano, lo maledicevano, volevano che invece di fermarsi dal Piola tornasse a casa con l’erba, con pannocchie di meliga, con pelli di coniglio, con **buse**.

Non capisco il significato di "buse" in questo brano e, nei dizionari che ho consultato, non ho trovato né "busa" né "buse". Forse si tratta di un termine di uso regionale. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono queste (o questi) "buse"?

Comment: Ho trovato qui https://books.google.it/books?id=G7JWAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&lpg=PT73&dq=cesare+pavese+buse&source=bl&ots=0zOoPAsvMx&sig=ACfU3U2MgNaByL0yMGeRAiQFdhLLbPUHEg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ3rKjj8viAhUENOwKHfozDj8Q6AEwDnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=cesare%20pavese%20buse&f=false che dovrebbe significare "sterco bovino"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ah! E, come avevo immaginato, è di origine piemontese.

Comment: Scusate, non mi sono ancora abituata a consultare il [Grande dizionario della lingua italiana](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI02/GDLI_02_ocr_465.pdf&parola=buse) (ho appena trovato qui la definizione di "busa").

Comment: In veneto *boassa* (la doppia "s" indica solo la pronuncia sorda).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La busa come correttamente indicato nei commenti è un termine di origine piemontese che indica gli escrementi della mucca.

In [questo dizionario di piemontese](https://digilander.libero.it/dotor43/vocpitoit1.html) si può trovare:

> **busa** - \ b'[ue]z& \ sost. f. escremento di mucca, cavallo, ecc. . Al plurale "buse".

Answer (score 2):

Ecco la definizione di "busa" che si può leggere sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI02/GDLI_02_ocr_465.pdf&parola=buse):

> **Busa,** sf. Dial. Sterco bovino. 
>  
>         *Jahier*, 91: Le vacche non buttano neanche abbastanza buse per contentare tutti i ragazzi che le raccattano e se le bisticciano calde ancora. *Pavese*, 5-87: Le due donne
>   lo chiamavano, lo maledicevano, volevano che invece di 
>   fermarsi dal Piola tornasse a casa con l’erba, con pannocchie di meliga, con pelli di coniglio, con buse.
>    
>         = Voce piemontese: *busa-*, cfr. fr. antico *bouse* (XII secolo), provenz. *bose*, di etimo sconosciuto.

Quindi, secondo questo dizionario, si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale piemontese col significato di "sterco bovino".

Comment: Può valer la pena notare che se è davvero cognato del Veneto *boassa*, l'etimologia è chiaramente collegata a *bò* (bue).